# ThreadLocal variable for SimpleDateFormat (OR) new SimpleDateFormat - Correct?

Tags: java, thread-safety

i come across [this article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue172.html) and got confused

In our project in few places we are using ThreadLocal for constructing ThreadLocal variable

In few other places we are constructing a new object SimpleDateFormat inside the private local method.

example,

```
private Date getConvertedDate(String Date){
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(); --> It is thread safe or not
}
```

Could someone clarify in detail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables that are created inside a method - live on the stack, thus they **are not shared across threads**. Each Thread has it's own stack. Declaring it inside a method, then working with it, then simply forgetting about it, would make it Thread Safe.

**After comments** here is a snippet:

```
public class DeleteMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DeleteMe me = new DeleteMe();
        me.go();
    }

    public void go() throws Exception {
        final Mutable mutable = new Mutable();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mutable.setT(57);
            }
        }).start();
        /** Main thread waits a bit to be sure that the custom Thread will start */
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(mutable.getT());
    }

    private class Mutable{
        public int t = 0;

        public int getT() {
            return t;
        }

        public void setT(int t) {
            this.t = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With a small comment added that the inner classes (if the variable declared final) can also access that variable if it is in scope, so technically this can be not thread safe, but this is quite easy to check.

Comment: Gabor could you please help with a sample code snippet?

Comment: @GáborBakos Method Local Inner classes can be accessed only by the thread that access the method itself, and even if the instance lives on the heap, there is no one who can reference it, thus change it.

Comment: @Eugene I am not sure you are right: `final SimpleDataFormat sdf = ...; new Thread() {public void run() {sdf.format(...);} }.start();`

Comment: @GáborBakos that is good point actually :) thx for the comment.

Comment: Also, there is an option to pass the variable to other methods (through stack, not heap), which also can mutate, so the safest option is the method local variable that is not used in inner classes, nor passed to other methods. Otherwise you have to review those methods/inner classes too.